Error : Please define a `secret` on attempt to deploy a Next.js with Auth.js application
I have set up the following variables both in the .env .env.local
AUTH_SECRET = generated 32 char length 
NEXTAUTH_URL = "https://website.vercel.app/api/auth"
AUTH_TRUST_HOST = true

And this is a fragment of my auth.ts file
export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth(
    {
        providers: [
            Credentials({
                name: "Credentials",
                credentials : {
                    username : {
                        label : "username", 
                        type : "text",
                        placeholder : "username"
                    },
                    password : {
                        label : "password",
                        type : "password",
                        placeholder : "password"
                    }
                },
    
                async authorize(credentials) {
                    ...
                }
                
            })
        ],
        basePath: process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL,
        callbacks: {
            async jwt({ token, user }) {
                if (user) {
                    token.role = user.role
                    token.username = user.username
                    token._id = user._id
                }
                return token
            },
            // If you want to use the role in client components
            async session({ session, token }) {
                if (session?.user) {
                    session.user.role = token.role as string
                    session.user.username = token.username as string
                    session.user._id = token._id as string
                }
                return session
            },
        },
        pages: {
            signIn: '/account/sign-in'
        },
        secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
    }
)

I also added the same parameters to the environment of Vercel where I am trying to deploy the application.
This the error taken from the logs of Vercel, and the application responses with a page that says the following

[31m[auth][error][0m MissingSecret: Please define a secret. Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#missingsecret
There was a problem with the server configuration. Check the server logs for more information

At this URL /api/auth/callback/credentials?
I also think that the error could be in the middleware.ts shown below :
import { auth } from "@/auth/auth"
 
// Export auth as middleware
export default auth;
 
// Optionally, configure middleware matcher
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    // Match all routes that should be protected
    "/dashboard/:path*",
    "/admin_panel/:path*",
    "/api/admin/:path*",
    // Exclude static files and API routes that need Node.js runtime
    "/((?!api/node|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)",
  ],
  unstable_allowDynamic: [
      // allows a single file
      "/lib/connectDB.ts",
      // use a glob to allow anything in the function-bind 3rd party module
      "/node_modules/mongoose/dist/**",
  ],
}


Configuration :
    "next": "14.2.14",
    "next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.25",

I tried to change the name of the variables both in the .env and .local.env to match the latest version standards

Please try to add NEXTAUTH_SECRET instead. BR
